# Why will this not work as a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, coding-style, command-prompt

When I type this on CMD it works but when I save it as a .bat it doesn't do anything.

```
C:\DP2U>for /f %a in (computers.txt) Do DelProf2.exe /D:30  /C:%a
```

How can I save this as a .bat so it does what I am trying to do? Thanks!

I am new to batch files....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) Do DelProf2.exe /D:30  /C:%%a
```

When you are using FOR command in batch script  you need double `%` to access the tokens.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your reply I was breaking my head and I thought about doing that but since I'm new to all this I hesitated.